# Developing a separate project with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

i want to create a class library project which will my data access layer project and there i want to generate edmx data model file with EF and want to communicate with my dal from my business layer which is a another separate project.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to do this it's pretty easy.

- Add a new project to your solution.
- Add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (EDMX file).
- Optionally add a DataAccess class/es to access the data.
- Add a reference to this project from your Business Layer project.

Comment: May I also suggest that if POCOs are used breaking them out into their own project as well.  That way if you're pushing them out all the way to the UI layer it will not need a reference to the DataAccess project, just to the BLL and Model.